# How can i simply detect mouse movement in python?

Tags: python, linux

How can i detect mouse movement in a python script in linux?

I want to then send those events to a handler which will dispatch that where i can process it later.

There is no gui installed if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

You could try reading `/dev/input/mice`.

Answer (score 1):

You can read from the event device node. But the data is a stream of structures. Here is some [python code](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/core/pycopia/OS/Linux/mouse.py) that does that already. You can use it as an example (or just use it). :-)